# Save value from two select statements in two different vaiables

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

What is the best and simplets way to save two values from two different select statements?

I have a query that's like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT FIELD1 FROM (<SUB SELECT STATMENT>)
UNION ALL
SELECT FIELD2 FROM (<SUB SELECT STATMENT>))
```

What I'd like is to save the value from FIELD1 and FIELD2 so later I can do some calulation with it, such as FIELD1 / FIELD2. I tried using a cursor but ran into issues. And it's too complicated for select statement. Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

The result set from my current query looks like this.

```
SUM_OF_MESSAGES  | LABEL
----------------------------
      145323     | PUSHED
      2633267    | RECEIVED
                 |
```

I'd like to take the values from the first two rows and divide them. Eg. 145323 / 2633267

In other words, is there a way to divide FIELD1 by FIELD2 from my above query?

ANOTHER UPDATE:

Here is my query:

```
SELECT SUM(R.MESSAGES) AS SUM_OF_MESSAGES, CASE WHEN R.LABEL = 1 THEN 'PUSHED' WHEN R.LABEL = 2 THEN 'RECEIVED' END AS LABEL FROM (                
SELECT SUM(Q.MESSAGES) AS "MESSAGES", 1 LABEL FROM (
SELECT USER_LOGIN,
                 EVENT_MSG,
                 ROW_LST_UPD_TS,
                 COMPONENT_NAME,
                 REGEXP_SUBSTR (SUBSTR (EVENT_MSG, INSTR (EVENT_MSG, ' ', 1, 1), INSTR (EVENT_MSG, ' ', 1, 1)), '[0-9]+') AS "MESSAGES"
            FROM EVENT_MGT.EVENT_LOG
            WHERE ROW_LST_UPD_TS BETWEEN (TRUNC (:DATEINPUT) - 1) + 5 / 86400 AND (TRUNC (:DATEINPUT)) + 5 / 86400
                 AND EVENT_ID = 101
                 AND COMPONENT_NAME LIKE '%Web ICE Downloader.exe%'
        GROUP BY COMPONENT_NAME,
                 USER_LOGIN,
                 EVENT_MSG,
                 ROW_LST_UPD_TS
                 ORDER BY ROW_LST_UPD_TS ) Q         
UNION ALL           
SELECT SUM(Q.MESSAGES) "MESSAGES", 2 LABEL FROM (
SELECT USER_LOGIN,
                 EVENT_MSG,
                 ROW_LST_UPD_TS,
                 COMPONENT_NAME,
                 REGEXP_SUBSTR (SUBSTR (EVENT_MSG, INSTR (EVENT_MSG, ' ', 1, 1), INSTR (EVENT_MSG, ' ', 1, 1)), '[0-9]+') AS "MESSAGES"
            FROM EVENT_MGT.EVENT_LOG
            WHERE ROW_LST_UPD_TS BETWEEN (TRUNC (:DATEINPUT) - 1) + 5 / 86400 AND (TRUNC (:DATEINPUT)) + 5 / 86400
                 AND EVENT_ID = 100
                 AND COMPONENT_NAME LIKE '%Web ICE Downloader.exe%'
        GROUP BY COMPONENT_NAME,
                 USER_LOGIN,
                 EVENT_MSG,
                 ROW_LST_UPD_TS
                 ORDER BY ROW_LST_UPD_TS ) Q ) R
                 GROUP BY  R.LABEL
```

Here is my result set:

```
SUM_OF_MESSAGES  | LABEL
----------------------------
      145323     | PUSHED
      2633267    | RECEIVED
                 |
```

I'd like to divide the two numbers in the same select statement. Please help.

Comment: I don't get it. This query can return any number of records, so what does it mean to say `FIELD1/FIELD2`?

Comment: What do u mean by saving it? Are you talking about in a stored procedure? Or in a programming language such as Java, C# or PHP?

Comment: Given the statement as written above, you'll only get back a single field named FIELD1.  I suspect that's not what you had in mind.  Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Bob Jarvis, please see above update. Churk, this is Oracle SQL. I'd like to keep it as a simple select, so no stored procedure. Chris Farmer, I want to take the value from the first sub query and the value from the second, and divide them in the select statement.

Comment: @Frank, but you can't unambiguously do that.  There's a huge gap between the pseudo-sql you have at the top of your question and the "result set" that you have at the bottom, and you're not providing enough detail for people to help you get to the last bit.

Comment: @Frank - Are your two queries scalar subqueries?  That is, will each one always return a single row of data?

Comment: Chris, please see second update

Comment: `SELECT (field1/field2) AS divided FROM (SELECT (<SUB SELECT>) AS field1, (<SUB SELECT>) AS field2 FROM dual)` this should work (I don't tried it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you would only need one query with a bit of logic in your aggregates

```
      SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN event_id = 100 
                         THEN q.messages
                         ELSE null
                     END) Received,
             COUNT( CASE WHEN event_id = 101
                         THEN q.messages 
                         ELSE null
                     END) Pushed,
             COUNT( CASE WHEN event_id = 101
                         THEN q.messages 
                         ELSE null
                     END) /
                COUNT( CASE WHEN event_id = 100 
                           THEN q.messages
                           ELSE null
                       END) Pushed_Over_Received
        FROM (
          SELECT USER_LOGIN,
                 EVENT_ID,
                 EVENT_MSG,
                 ROW_LST_UPD_TS,
                 COMPONENT_NAME,
                 REGEXP_SUBSTR (SUBSTR (EVENT_MSG, INSTR (EVENT_MSG, ' ', 1, 1), 
                 INSTR (EVENT_MSG, ' ', 1, 1)), '[0-9]+') AS "MESSAGES"
            FROM EVENT_MGT.EVENT_LOG
            WHERE ROW_LST_UPD_TS BETWEEN (TRUNC (:DATEINPUT) - 1) + 5 / 86400 
                                     AND (TRUNC (:DATEINPUT)) + 5 / 86400
              AND EVENT_ID in( 100, 101 )
              AND COMPONENT_NAME LIKE '%Web ICE Downloader.exe%'
        )
```

Alternately, you could do something like this with analytic functions (you'd want to replace the subquery `t` in my query with the query you've written that produces the two rows of output)

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with t as (
  2    select 145323 sum_of_messages, 'PUSHED' label from dual
  3    union all
  4    select 2633267, 'RECEIVED' from dual
  5  )
  6  select sum_of_messages,
  7         label,
  8         round( 100*ratio_to_report(sum_of_messages) over (), 2) pct_of_messages
  9*   from t
SQL> /

SUM_OF_MESSAGES LABEL    PCT_OF_MESSAGES
--------------- -------- ---------------
         145323 PUSHED              5.23
        2633267 RECEIVED           94.77
```

Comment: Justin. Beautiful. Thank you. You're first option work great.